# Any downside to using timestamp without time zone if UTC is ok at all times

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

`timestamp with time zone` vs `timestamp without time zone`:

I'm aware that `timestamptz` is the same as timestamp no time-zone + (time-zone difference) that gets added upon saving a value in a database. That is, in a db, when stored, they both are indistinguishable.

Say, I decide to use `timestamp without time zone` only, even in cases where `timestamp with time zone` would be recommended. And users of my website are ok with keeping in mind that I and they would be operating with UTC at all times, even if we happen to be in different time zones physically, would `timestamp without time zone` work out well and with no flaws?

Answer (score 6):

If all are aware that the timestamp value is supposed to represent UTC time it should work, basically. A convenient advantage is that default input and output is less noisy.

I would still suggest **`timestamptz`**. Here are some reasons:

#### 1.

`timestamptz` literally is the "preferred type" among date/time types in Postgres. See:

```
test=> SELECT typname, typispreferred FROM pg_type WHERE typcategory = 'D';
   typname   | typispreferred 
-------------+----------------
 date        | f
 time        | f
 timestamp   | f
 timestamptz | t  -- !
 timetz      | f
 time_stamp  | f
(6 rows)
```

[The manual about `pg_types`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html#CATALOG-TYPCATEGORY-TABLE)

This can work in favor of `timestamptz` in corner cases of type/function/operator resolution.

#### 2.

When you have `timestamptz` literals as data input, that just works with type `timestamptz`:

```
'2020-04-22 04:46:46.790969+02'
```

Inserting the same into a `timestamp` column would ignore the time offset (lose information). One would have to cast to `timestamptz` explicitly, then transpose to UTC timestamp with something like:

```
'2020-04-22 04:46:46.790969+02'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

The opposite direction is less error prone. When inserting a `timestamp` literal into a `timestamptz` column, the current time zone is assumed in the absence of explicit information.

#### 3.

`now()` and `transaction_timestamp()` return `timestamptz`. If you need `timestamp`, you have to cast. Internally, `LOCALTIMESTAMP` does just that: it casts `transaction_timestamp()`. To get the current timestamp for UTC you need `now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` or similar.

#### 4.

*Displaying* timestamps for a given time zone is simpler based on `timestamptz`:

```
SELECT my_timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'US/Hawaii';
```

That's more work with `timestamp`. *We* know it's supposed to be UTC time. But Postgres does not until we say so, explicitly:

```
SELECT my_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Hawaii'
```

Related:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)